# Visual Basic Replace is not working

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a simple hangman program and I want to replace something in my variable which stores the letters of the word that have been found.

Here is the code:

```
    Replace(wordLettersFound, Mid(wordLettersFound, counter, 1), letter)
```

wordLettersFound, counter and letter are 3 of the variables I am using.

The variable is all underscores before this script, but it does not change! Can anyone help me with this?

P.S.
I do not know what version of VB I am using, visual studio community 2015 just says 'visual basic'.

Comment: You're developing the app in VS 2015 and yet you are using the old `Replace()` and `Mid()` functions which was supported in versions up to VS 2008?

Comment: @AndrewMorton : I am well aware of that, but I think one should not get used to these old methods since they _might_ get removed some day. -- I think all these kinds of old methods should be put in the compability namespace, and have the documentation tutorials rewritten to include the new methods.

Comment: @VisualVincent There are advantages to using the VB.NET methods instead of the framework methods, but let's not go there in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Replace` doesn't modify the string but returns a new string with the replacement so you should assign it to the variable:

```
wordLettersFound = Replace(wordLettersFound, Mid(wordLettersFound, counter, 1), letter)
```

Comment: Thanks, my code now changes the letter, however the changed letter is positioned right after the last changed letter, instead of in its correct position, e.g. ship is sp__ instead of s__p. Here is the code:

Comment: If Mid(wordLettersFound, counter, 1) = "_" Then
                    wordLettersFound = Replace(wordLettersFound, Mid(wordLettersFound, counter, 1), letter, 1, 1, 0)
                End If

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do replace,

```
    Dim theLetters As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzAAA"

    theLetters = theLetters.Replace("A"c, "@"c)
```

Comment: what would the result be?

Comment: ah, yes, but I want to replace a specific section, not all of that string.

Comment: What do you mean by section?  A group of characters?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to replace a character in a string. Using the Replace function is a bit awkward in your case because, at the start, *all* the characters are underscores - Replace as you're using it will replace all of them with the found character.

Instead, you can cut up the string to the piece to the left of the desired replacement, add in the replacement character, and add on the rest of the string. That line is the one after the comment "chop foundWord up and put the character in the right place" in this code:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim wordToFind = "alphabet"
        ' make a string of dashes the same length as the word to find
        Dim foundWord = New String("-"c, wordToFind.Length)

        While foundWord <> wordToFind
            Console.Write("Enter your guess for a letter: ")

            Dim guess = Console.ReadLine()
            ' make sure the user has only entered one character
            If guess.Length = 1 Then
                ' see if the letter is in the string
                Dim pos = wordToFind.IndexOf(guess)
                While pos >= 0
                    ' chop foundWord up and put the character in the right place
                    foundWord = foundWord.Substring(0, pos) & guess & foundWord.Substring(pos + 1)
                    ' see if there are any more of the same letter
                    pos = wordToFind.IndexOf(guess, pos + 1)
                End While

                ' show the user the current progress
                Console.WriteLine(foundWord)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter just one letter!")
            End If

        End While

        Console.WriteLine("You did it!")

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to leave the program.")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

**N.B.** Do not use all that code directly for homework because your teacher *will* find this. And that goes to anyone else doing homework - you know who you are ;)

Comment: Haha this wasn't actually homework. We did get a piece a year after I made this though, but by then I'd learned arrays which were much easier to use ;)